# Join unrelated tables in summarized manner

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am finding a hard time to summarize the SQL table.

```
Objective: from the given tables I have to join and summarize the table.
col1 = Name_of_student, 
col2 = Name_of_subject(where she/he scored highest), 
col3= highest_number, 
col4 = faculty_Name(where she/he scored highest),
col5 = Name_of_subject(where she/he scored lowest), 
col6 = lowest marks, 
col7 = faculty_Name(where she/he scored lowest)
```

**Note** - I have to write only one query for the given output.

There four tables:

1. Students.
2. Students_subject.
3. Faculty.
4. Marks.

You can copy the code in my SQL script for understanding the tables.

```
 create database university ;
    use university ;

    create table students (id int auto_increment primary key,
    student_name varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
    dob DATE NOT NULL) ;

    create table faculty ( id int auto_increment primary key,
    faculty_name varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    date_of_update datetime default NOW()) ;


     create table Students_subject ( id int auto_increment primary key,
     subject_name varchar(250) default 'unknown' NOT NULL,
     subject_faculty int not null,
     foreign key(subject_faculty) references faculty(id));

    create table marks (id int auto_increment primary key,
    student_id int NOT NULL,
    subject_id int NOT NULL,
    marks int NOT NULL,
    date_of_update datetime default now() ON UPDATE NOW(),
    foreign key(student_id) references students(id),
    foreign key(subject_id) references students_subject(id));

    insert into students ( student_name, dob) values 
    ('rob', '2001-03-06'),
    ('bbb', '2001-09-06'),
    ('rab', '1991-03-06'),
    ('root', '2001-03-16') ;


    insert into faculty(faculty_name) values
    ('kaka'),
    ('dope'),
    ('kallie'),
    ('kim');

    insert into students_subject (subject_name, subject_faculty) values
    ('maths', 2),
    ('physics', 3),
    ('english', 4),
    ('biology', 1),
    ('statistics', 2),
    ('french', 4),
    ('economics',3);


    insert into marks ( student_id, subject_id, marks) values
    (1,1,70),
    (1,2,60),
    (1,3,98),
    (1,4,75),
    (1,5,90),
    (1,6,30),
    (1,7,40),
    (2,1,70),
    (2,2,60),
    (2,3,70),
    (2,4,105),
    (2,5,95),
    (2,6,30),
    (2,7,10),
    (3,1,70),
    (3,2,60),
    (3,3,70),
    (3,4,75),
    (3,5,99),
    (3,6,30),
    (3,7,10),
    (4,1,70),
    (4,2,60),
    (4,3,70),
    (4,4,89),
    (4,5,99),
    (4,6,30),
    (4,7,19);
```

I had written Query myself to work out on this but cannot break it though.

```
select students.id, table_high.marks, table_high.faculty_name as high_faculty, table_high.subject_name as sub_high,
student_low.marks , student_low.faculty_name as faculty_low, student_low.subject_name as sub_low from students
inner join
(select students.id, students.student_name ,marks.marks, subject_joined.faculty_name, students_subject.subject_name from marks
inner join (select  students_subject.id,students_subject.subject_name, faculty.faculty_name, students_subject.subject_faculty
from students_subject left join faculty on students_subject.subject_faculty = faculty.id)
as subject_joined on subject_joined.id = marks.subject_id
inner join faculty on subject_joined.subject_faculty = faculty.id
inner join students_subject on students_subject.id = marks.subject_id
inner join students on students.id = marks.student_id 
order by 1, 3 desc) as table_high on table_high.id = students.id
inner join 
(select students.id, students.student_name ,marks.marks, subject_joined.faculty_name, students_subject.subject_name from marks
inner join (select  students_subject.id,students_subject.subject_name, faculty.faculty_name, students_subject.subject_faculty
from students_subject left join faculty on students_subject.subject_faculty = faculty.id)
as subject_joined on subject_joined.id = marks.subject_id
inner join faculty on subject_joined.subject_faculty = faculty.id
inner join students_subject on students_subject.id = marks.subject_id
inner join students on students.id = marks.student_id 
order by 1, 3 ) as student_low on student_low.id = students.id
group by 1 ;
```

attaching screen of output :

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Please google `Group By` and aggregation functions. Try some query, and edit the question to add your latest attempt.

Comment: Welkom on Stackoverflow, Stackoverflow isn't a free coding service or home work, job interview helping website.. We are willing to help you if you atleast show a attempted query yourself... it's in how to ask in the Stackoverflow guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask qouted from that link "Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, **and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself**. "

Comment: Dear Raymond, The following question is a self-thought question which I am unable to resolve. It is neither a homework based question nor dumping on the website for resolution. I have tried many attempts but cannot come to a resolution with an accurate single query. I have searched for many resolutions also but couldn't find one suiting to my problem Though I hadn't posted my input before thinking it may sound ridicule. You could have a look now.

Comment: @MohammedTaherPansari do you have access to MySQL server version >= 8.0.2 ? This is a Window function problem. Also edit the question and add the expected output values (as per your sample data).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I have edited the question and added sample output screenshot for reference. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this question!

The basic tweak that was required in summarizing this table is that the sub-table had to be joined with a combination of two columns as group by command just reflects the first row value in the summarized table for non-summarized cols, so reflecting values of max and min was not possible at the same time, to which I created sub tables filtering rows through double column joins and finally joined the table to the main student table.

The main table which was joined is Students.

Sub-Table 1 - hw (which summarized the data for highest)
sub-table 1.2 - high for highest marks tagging.
sub-table 2  - lw ( which summarized the table for the lowest) 
sub-table 2.1 - low for minimum marks tagging.

Query >>

```
select students.id, students.student_name, lw.min_marks, lw.lower_subject, lw.lower_faculty, 
hw.high_marks, hw.subject_name as high_subject, hw.faculty_name as higher_faculty
from students inner join
(select high.student_id, high.high_marks, high.subject_id, high.subject_name, high.faculty_name
from 
(select marks.student_id, marks.marks as high_marks, sub_with_faculty.subject_id, sub_with_faculty.subject_name,
sub_with_faculty.faculty_name from marks
left join
(select students_subject.id as subject_id, students_subject.subject_name, faculty.faculty_name
from students_subject  
left join faculty  on  students_subject.subject_faculty = faculty.id) as sub_with_faculty
on sub_with_faculty.subject_id = marks.subject_id) as high
inner join (select marks.student_id, max(marks) as marks from marks group by 1) as maximum on 
maximum.student_id = high.student_id and maximum.marks = high.high_marks) as hw on
hw.student_id = students.id
inner join
(select low.student_id, low.low_marks as min_marks, low.subject_id as lower_subjectID, low.subject_name as lower_subject, low.faculty_name as lower_faculty
from 
(select marks.student_id, marks.marks as low_marks, sub_with_faculty.subject_id, sub_with_faculty.subject_name,
sub_with_faculty.faculty_name from marks
left join
(select students_subject.id as subject_id, students_subject.subject_name, faculty.faculty_name
from students_subject  
left join faculty  on  students_subject.subject_faculty = faculty.id) as sub_with_faculty
on sub_with_faculty.subject_id = marks.subject_id) as low
inner join (select marks.student_id, min(marks) as marks from marks group by 1) as minimum on 
minimum.student_id = low.student_id and minimum.marks = low.low_marks) as lw on 
lw.student_id = students.id;
```

This could be a good exercise for someone who's new to MySQL like me.